# Design pattern to keep UI text separate from UI widgets

Tags: user-interface, shiny

The R Shiny app I am building is going to require both (1) some large blocks of text in the UI, and (2) some complexity in the UI design. I am concerned that combining this all into the same file will create significant clutter. Hence, I am looking for a design pattern to help keep the UI-text separate from the UI-functionality.

For example, the following code includes alternating text and functionality.

- Editing UI-text will require navigating around chunks of UI-functionality.
- Editing UI-functionality will require navigating around chunks of UI-text.

```r
# chunk of functionality
tabPanel(
  title = title,
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
      wellPanel(

        # chunk of text
        h4("heading text"),
        p("lots of text in this paragraph"),
        p("lots of text in this paragraph"),

      # chunk of functionality
      ),
      div(style = "height:3px"),
      hr(),
      actionButton("button1"), "label1"),
      wellPanel(

        # chunk of text
        h4("heading text"),
        p("lots of text in this paragraph"),
        p("lots of text in this paragraph")

      )
)))
```

Approaches I have considered:

1. Every chunk of text could be pulled out into its own shiny module. However, this seems overkill when there is no server functionality for each piece of text.
2. Create the text chunks using the server and insert them into the UI. However, this will likely just move the complexity into the server and may impact performance as the server has to pass all the text to the UI.
3. Creating a list that stores all the text chunks and insert text from this list seems the best candidate approach, but it is not clear how/if this will handle text that needs to be updated while the app runs.

I accept that whatever design pattern I choose will also constrain the development approach. But I have struggled to find *any* discussion of the handling of UI text, and no discussion of how to approach this in Shiny.

What is an effective design/development pattern to keep UI-text and UI-functionality separate?

Comment: Have you considered using a package like `shiny.i18n`? Though it seems you do not want to localize, this would solve your problem. It would be close to you 3rd solution AND it would allow you to change text in the UI during run time (at least as long as you switch the complete data base of text).

Comment: You don't need a Shiny module, an ordinary function is enough.

Comment: I suggest creating functions containing the texts, save them in the `global.R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design pattern I ended up using matches the suggestions of @Stephane and @Vida.

**app file**

```r
# chunk of functionality
tabPanel(
  title = title,
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
      wellPanel(

        text_chunk_1()

      # chunk of functionality
      ),
      div(style = "height:3px"),
      hr(),
      actionButton("button1"), "label1"),
      wellPanel(

        text_chunk_2("heading goes here")

      )
)))
```

**supporting file**

```r
text_chunk_1 = function() {
  tagList(
    h4("heading text"),
    p("lots of text in this paragraph"),
    p("lots of text in this paragraph")
  )
}

text_chunk_2 = function(heading_text) {
  tagList(
    h4(heading_text),
    p("lots of text in this paragraph"),
    p("lots of text in this paragraph")
  )
}
```

Adding this abstraction also prompted me to abstract out other parts of the app. For example: where chunks of functionality are repetitive, the reused parts could also be moved out into a supporting file.

Note that once I moved more than just the text strings to the supporting file, the functions need to return a `tagList`. For example:

- `"paragraph text"` can be returned without a tagList
- it might work to return one `p("paragraph text")` by itself though I would prefer a tagList
- but two or more items need a tagList:

  - `p("paragraph1"), p("paragraph2")` will fail
  - `tagList( p("paragraph1"), p("paragraph2") )` will work